# CSS Scroll Perspective on Nested Elements

Tags: html, css, css-transforms, perspective

The following code produces a perspective effect that changes the angle you are looking at the element, as you scroll:

[image: scrolling]

```
<div class="parent"> 
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div
</div>
```

```
* {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.nesting {
  height: 3000px;
}

.parent {
  overflow: scroll;
  perspective: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  transform: rotateX(50deg);
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/Davste93/pen/ZEydJeK

However this is not very practical for real-world situations, because the moment you add an element in between the parent and transformed element (see: nesting), it breaks:

```
<div class="parent"> 
  <div class="nesting">
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: scrolling not working]

Isn't this what preserve-3d, is meant to do? Nothing seems to work.

**Is there a way to get CSS perspective animations to work on scroll with elements in between?**

I know I can achieve the same effect with perspective-origin and javascript, but I would like to keep this in pure CSS if possible.

Comment: I said "impractical" because it makes things like layout, multiple animated elements on the page, components, etc - much more difficult if you are scrolling on, say body, but I'm open to other ideas.

Comment: First thing I tried - doesn't work. There's a codepen - you can see here: https://codepen.io/Davste93/pen/ZEydJeK

Comment: Safari and Chrome seem to both hate it

Comment: Try to add `perspective: 400px;` not `transform-style`

Comment: @Greg-- That adds the perspective but breaks the scrolling effect. The angle you are viewing the elements should change as you are scrolling. See the working one here: https://codepen.io/Davste93/pen/dyRBmBm

Comment: can you explain why do you need nested element?

Answer (score 4):

I found out a few things on this journey:

1. overflow: hidden breaks perspective, even when there's preserve-3d
2. preserve-3d is needed on any nested elements
3. Angular components (unless they have display: block) do not pass down perspective.

Working example:

```
<div class="parent"> 
  <div class="nesting">
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div>
    <div class="box"/> </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```
* {
  height: 100%;
}

html {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.nesting {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.parent {
  overflow: scroll;
  perspective: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
}

.box {
  width: 100px; height: 100px;
  margin: 100px auto;
  border: 5px solid black;
  transform: rotateX(50deg);
}
```

https://codepen.io/Davste93/pen/jOwjxOP